# View not updating when autolayout constraint modified programmatically

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, autolayout

I'm having trouble getting my view to lay itself out properly after modifying a second constraint (the first works fine). I'm modifying one constraint, animating it, and then modifying another constraint in the completion block (without animation).

My reason for doing this is I don't want the second constraint change to affect the animation, but I want it to instantly take effect as soon as the initial animation completes.

The problem is the second constraint change is simply not taking effect, no matter what I try.

Here's what I'm trying (note the problem is only when `toolbarVisible` is `YES`, as I perform both animations up front when it is `NO`):

```
    if ( !toolbarVisible )
        self.containerViewBottomSpace.constant = toolbarVisible ? 60.f : 0;
    self.toolbarBottomSpace.constant = toolbarVisible ? 0 : 60.f; // this one works fine
    [self.view setNeedsUpdateConstraints];
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3f animations:^{
        [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        if ( toolbarVisible )
            self.containerViewBottomSpace.constant = 60.f; // this one is not taking effect
        [self.view setNeedsUpdateConstraints];
        [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
    }];
```

The above method takes place inside an `observeValueForKeyPath:...` method. I've tried wrapping the whole above code in a `dispatch_after` block, but that has an even worse effect in that it is always one step behind (i.e. containerView is always in the opposite position as it should be) as if the second constraint modification isn't taking effect until the *next* animation.

Similarly, if I push another view onto the navigation controller (which is embedded inside the containerView), the layout corrects itself. It's as though it's just ignoring my command to lay itself out again for some reason.

Actually I just noticed that even if I make the second change initially and skip the completion block altogether, it doesn't appear to be animating the second constraint change in all cases. Something is fishy.

**Update:** I was using `dispatch_after` incorrectly thinking it accepted an NSTimeInterval. After giving it a proper `dispatch_time_t` and putting it inside the completion block, the layout is now *sometimes* updating. However, it's very flaky and this seems very hackish so I feel as though I'm missing something. If anyone knows more about this please enlighten me and I'll give you the answer.

**Update 2:** I decided to try logging the height of the element I am trying to change in `viewDidLayoutSubviews`. Interestingly, it gets called twice, first with the previous value and second with the correctly adjusted height. So I guess it is at least *partially* laying things out correctly, but for some reason the tableView that is inside the containerView is still not resizing itself properly. I'm not sure what I'm missing.

Answer (score 0):

I'd first breakpoint and make sure you're not hitting the animation code a second time during the animation duration.  If it's in observeValueForKeyPath you could hit the animation multiple times and it causes some inconsistency.

You also shouldn't need to call setNeedsUpdateConstraints or layoutIfNeeded.  Setting the constant should be enough.

I'd also make sure that you've got the constraints wired up correctly and toolbarVisible is true.

Comment: I'm logging some debug statements to make sure it's only being called once and when expected. The constraints are wired correctly because the change does eventually take effect, just not immediately when it should. For example if I rotate the device, it all of a sudden renders correctly including if I rotate back to the original orientation.