# setNeedsLayout or layoutIfNeeded necessary after changing constraint constant?

Tags: ios, autolayout, constraints

On iOS, is it necessary to make any API calls (such as `setNeedsLayout` or `layoutIfNeeded`) after changing a constraint's constant programmatically?  In my use case, I'm not interested in animating the change.  I believe there are some bugs (e.g.: [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25033653/ios-updating-auto-layout-constraint-constant-stops-working-after-pushing-anoth)) where calling those functions is a workaround.  But other than that edge case I haven't needed to call them in my code.  Does this just happen to work by chance or is there a definitive source that mentions what to do when changing constraint constants?

A couple of SO answers ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26513276/3022390) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23963530/3022390)) say that setting the constant should be enough, but without any supporing reference.

Apple's iOS Auto Layout Guide doesn't mention anything about it except in an [animation block](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/AutoLayoutbyExample/AutoLayoutbyExample.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010853-CH5-SW1).  The Cocoa [Auto Layout Release Notes](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/releasenotes/UserExperience/RNAutomaticLayout/#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010631-CH1-SW14) do say that calling `setNeedsLayout` is unnecessary unless you also override `layout` in your custom view.  However, that document seems rather OSX specific.

Answer (score 0):

If want to get the correct frame of view immediately, you should call these APIs manually. (e.g. Get animation begin/end frame) Or we don't need to call these APIs manually.

I use MASConstraint framework and I never call these APIs.

I am not sure if it's necessary when you add/remove constraint but not update Constraint. :(

Answer (score -2):

Yes, it is necessary to call `setNeedsLayout` after changing the `constant` of a layout constraint, as this change alone does not count as an invalidation of the layout.

Comment: Unfortunately I could not find this information in the official documentation yet.

Comment: Wrong, it doesn't. it's called automatically.